# How to delete lines from csv file using python?

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file:It contain the classes name and type of code smell and for each class Icalculated the number of a code smell .the final calcul is on the last line so there are many repeated classes name . 
I need just the last line of the class name.

This is a part of my CSV file beacause it's too long :

```
NameOfClass,LazyClass,ComplexClass,LongParameterList,FeatureEnvy,LongMethod,BlobClass,MessageChain,RefusedBequest,SpaghettiCode,SpeculativeGenerality
com.nirhart.shortrain.MainActivity,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,1,NaN,NaN,NaN
com.nirhart.shortrain.path.PathParser,NaN,1,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
com.nirhart.shortrain.path.PathParser,NaN,1,NaN,1,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
com.nirhart.shortrain.path.PathParser,NaN,1,1,1,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
com.nirhart.shortrain.path.PathParser,NaN,1,2,1,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
com.nirhart.shortrain.path.PathParser,NaN,1,2,1,1,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
com.nirhart.shortrain.path.PathPoint,1,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
com.nirhart.shortrain.path.PathPoint,1,NaN,1,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
com.nirhart.shortrain.path.TrainPath,NaN,NaN,NaN,1,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
com.nirhart.shortrain.rail.RailActionActivity,NaN,NaN,NaN,1,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
com.nirhart.shortrain.rail.RailActionActivity,NaN,NaN,NaN,1,1,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
```

Comment: What went wrong with the implementation from your research? Did you get errors?

Comment: I did not find any similar problem and I'm beginner and it's not easy to me ! when i search i found who deleted lines from a specific index !

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Do you want to actually delete lines from the CSV (as stated)? Or do you want to read/parse just the last line of the file? Do you want to read/parse the last line of every block of lines that have matching class name? Or something else?

Comment: I need to keep from the csv file just the last line of every block of lines that have matching class name and delete the rest !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter out the last entry for groups of `NameOfClass`, you can make use of Python's `groupby()` function to return lists of rows with the same `NameOfClass`. The last entry from each can then be written to a file.

```
from itertools import groupby
import csv

with open('data_in.csv', newline='') as f_input, open('data_out.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)

    for key, rows in groupby(csv_input, key=lambda x: x[0]):
        csv_output.writerow(list(rows)[-1])
```

For the data you have given, this would give you the following output:

```
NameOfClass,LazyClass,ComplexClass,LongParameterList,FeatureEnvy,LongMethod,BlobClass,MessageChain,RefusedBequest,SpaghettiCode,SpeculativeGenerality
com.nirhart.shortrain.MainActivity,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,1,NaN,NaN,NaN
com.nirhart.shortrain.path.PathParser,NaN,1,2,1,1,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
com.nirhart.shortrain.path.PathPoint,1,NaN,1,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
com.nirhart.shortrain.path.TrainPath,NaN,NaN,NaN,1,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
com.nirhart.shortrain.rail.RailActionActivity,NaN,NaN,NaN,1,1,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

To get just the unique class names (*ignoring* repeated rows, not *deleting* them), you can do this:

```
import csv

with open('my_file.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    classNames = set(row[0] for row in reader)  
print(classNames)
# {'com.nirhart.shortrain.MainActivity', 'com.nirhart.shortrain.path.PathParser', 'com.nirhart.shortrain.path.PathPoint', ...}
```

This is just using the `csv` module to open a file, getting the first value in each row, and then taking only the unique values of those. You can then manipulate the resulting set of strings (you might want to cast it back to a `list` via `list(classNames)`) however you need to.

Comment: thank you but i need the result in the same csv file . Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to later process the data in pandas, filtering duplicates is trivial:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
df = df.loc[~df.NameOfClass.duplicated(keep='last')]
```

If you just want to build a new csv file with only the expected lines, pandas is overkill and the csv module is enough:

```
import csv

with open('file.csv') as fdin, file('new_file.csv', 'w', newline='') as fdout:
    rd = csv.reader(fdin)
    wr = csv.writer(fdout)
    wr.writerow(next(rd))    # copy the header line
    old = None
    for row in rd:
        if old is not None and old[0] != row[0]:
            wr.writerow(old)
        old = row
    wr.writerow(old)
```